# Spring 3.1 without persistence.xml gives "Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL"

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to use [JPA EntityManagerFactory bootstrapping without persistence.xml](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#d0e1489), which is new in Spring 3.1 (since M2), but it appears that spring is still searching for a `persistence.xml` file, despite the fact that `packagesToScan` is specified.

In context.xml, the entityManagerFactory is configured thusly:

```
<bean id="my-persistence-unit"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass"
        value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>my.package.name</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But on application startup, a `PersistenceException` with message "Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL" occurs:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'my-persistence-unit' defined in class path resource [META-INF/context.xml]: 
...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:429)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:327)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:309)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:209)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442)
        ... 34 more 
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:179)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:426)
        ... 40 more
```

Before I added `packagesToScan`, I had a minimal `persistence.xml`, and set the `persistenceXmlLocation`, like so:

```
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
    value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
```

which worked fine. So what am I doing incorrectly now?

**edit** added `jpaVendorAdapter`, error remains.

**edit** removed persistenceUnitName per a deleted comment; renamed beans to the persistence unit name (for `@PersistenceContext`)

**update** this error seems to depend upon which kind of application context loader is used. The code works in a spring/junit test via `@ContextConfiguration`, but not via `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bug in Spring, I [reported it](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8832).

Note that it happens only for a packaged application, when all classpath items are jars. That's why it doesn't fail in unit tests.

Comment: Great, I guess I'll keep my minimal persistence.xml for now and see how they respond to the bug report.

Comment: Any news about this? The release date for 1.1.1 says today?

Comment: Note that despite the bug being closed as fixed in 3.1.1 it is still broken in 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this class allows you to completly remove the persistence.xml file. From its javadoc:

"However, this FactoryBean is more flexible in that you can override the location of the persistence.xml file, specify the JDBC DataSources to link to, etc."

I think what it does is allow you to have a minimal persistence.xml file and then let you further configure the EMF proframatically via listeners etc.

Comment: Really? The doc I linked to says "Effectively, this allows for XML-free JPA setup at the mere expense of specifying a base package for entity scanning"

Comment: Also "In case of Spring-based scanning, no persistence.xml is necessary;" from http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan%28java.lang.String...%29

Comment: Well you copied the guy's code wrong. Its: <property name="jpaPropertyMap"> not <property name="jpaProperties">. And you need to add  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"> as well.

Comment: jpaProperties and jpaPropertyMap are both valid, and do the same thing. I added jpaVendorAdapter, but the error remains.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is the extent of all my knowledge on this. Take not that this is not a final release of this version of Spring, so you might have stumbled over a bug.