# Spring Data JPA : class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I'm kinda new to Spring but I decided to use Spring-Data-JPA for a personal project.
I started following ["Accessing Data with JPA"](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) tutorial but with my own modification. (as you can see below)

When running my code I get the exception:

```
...
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class dal.access.DBAccess: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1548)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at dal.test.Application.main(Application.java:20)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:529)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:402)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:285)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1544)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:178)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:526)
    ... 23 more
```

This exception is similar to an [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052535/spring-3-1-without-persistence-xml-gives-unable-to-resolve-persistence-unit-roo) here that seemed to be resolved back then, this is why I am not sure it's the same case...

Maybe I'm using an old spring product so, my 'build.gradle' file is as following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:0.5.0.M6")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src"]
        }
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'dal-jar-test'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
    maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:0.5.0.M6")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.0.RC1")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.4.1.RELEASE")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.1.Final")
    compile("com.h2database:h2:1.3.172")
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.11")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.8'
}
```

My code is as following:

The **POJO** class:

```
package dal.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long    id;
    private String  firstName;
    private String  lastName;

    protected EntityA() {}

    public EntityA(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName  =   firstName;
        this.lastName   =   lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("EntityA[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                             id,firstName,lastName);
    }
}
```

The **Repository** Interface:

```
package dal.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import dal.entities.EntityA;

public interface EntityARepository extends CrudRepository<EntityA, Long> {
    List<EntityA> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

The access layer:

```
package dal.access;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

public class DBAccess {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("dal.repositories");

        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);

        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

and finally the main class:

```
package dal.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import dal.access.DBAccess;
import dal.entities.EntityA;
import dal.repositories.EntityARepository;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DBAccess.class);
        EntityARepository repositoryA = ctx.getBean(EntityARepository.class);

        // save a couple entities
        repositoryA.save(new EntityA("boy", "boy"));
        repositoryA.save(new EntityA("girl", "girl"));

        // fetch all entities
        Iterable<EntityA> As = repositoryA.findAll();
        for (EntityA entityA : As) {
            System.out.println(entityA);
        }

        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see by the code each class is at a different package. (maybe this is the problem because when I'm creating all the classes at the same package everything works perfectly) The exception is risen when running the gradle generated jar with the java command-line.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example you've provided and the Spring data sample project:

If you place your entities into different package, you should specify explicitly the packages where spring should look for these entities, it can't really scan all the project, because its not reasonable both from the performance point of view and memory consumption.

So, in your example the entity exists in "dal.entities" package. 
You should configure the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean like this:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    lef.setPackagesToScan("dal.entities"); // !!! you might want to place here more than one package, its vararg
    return lef;
}
```

I've downloaded the sample project (I don't have gradle, so I've used maven build), placed the entity in the different package and it worked).

If you don't want to configure your stuff like you might want to consider to create a persistence xml that will specify the list of these entities but its a totally different story.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer mark! But when I changed the packages to scan like you suggested another exception was risen: **NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**, after that I understood that the annotations put on my **Application** class was needed to be moved to the **DBAccess** class, furthermore I needed to add the the **basePackages** attribute to the **@EnableJpaRepositories** annotation which will let spring find my repositories class and implement them.